# Count of comments and likes are not shown in feed and comments

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hy well how does the url looks when you use a PageID and at the same time want the count of all comments and likes back I tried it hard way

```
$feed_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$row[0].'/feed&access_token=$access_token&limit=500',"get");
$post_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$row[0].'/comments?access_token=$access_token&limit=500',"get");
```

also tried comments& instead of comments?

I dont know how to get back the comments and likes what must I exactly do my var $row[0] stores various Pages from fb

Answer (score 0):

the feed has connections EG: comments, likes that provide the count.

---

```
    $feed_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$row[0].'/feed&access_token=$access_token&limit=5',"get");
// get comment/like count for first post in array.  this can be done with a loop.
    echo 'Comments: '.$feed_profile[data][0][comments][count].'<br />';
    echo 'Likes:    '.$feed_profile[data][0][likes][count].'';
```

---

> **NOTE:** you will have to account for error handling, when no comments or
>   likes have been made the connections arrays do not exsist

Comment: feed seems deprecated for a Page I can get the data but for a thread ID I cannot use the api call to get back all messages without OAuth crashing up the system